# How/where to add jquery scripts with ASP.NET Core 2 Angular/Typescript project?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I think everything is in the title.
I started a new ASP.NET Core 2 with Angular and Typescript project and I got an easy component that require some scripts to be executed. The component is a responsive YouTube video background, I found at : `https://codepen.io/ccrch/pen/GgPLVW`

Where should I add the scripts code you see with the codepen url?
If I add it to the HTML file associate with the component below, the scripts are removed by Angular. I cannot add it either in the _layout.cshtml page without, I think, broke the Angular architecture.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'html5video',
    templateUrl: './html5video.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./html5video.component.css'],

})

export class Html5VideoComponent {

}
```

Thank you very any guidance